How to set OS disk size of container running a process
I am running Nextflow with AzureBatch. The VM's are created with an OS disk of 1000GB. The containers are created during the workflow with an working disk size of ~90GB. I need the container disks to be 200GB.
I have tried:
process {
    executor = 'azurebatch'
    queue = 'arm_pool_standard_d4_v3'
    container = params.container
    errorStrategy = 'ignore'    
    containerOptions = '--storage-opt dm.basesize=200G'

and
process {
    executor = 'azurebatch'
    queue = 'arm_pool_standard_d4_v3'
    container = params.container
    errorStrategy = 'ignore'    
    disk = '200.GB'

and
process {
    executor = 'azurebatch'
    queue = 'arm_pool_standard_d4_v3'
    container = params.container
    errorStrategy = 'ignore'    
    disk = '200 GB'

The result is always:
Docker Container: az-pass
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1        98G  2.5G   91G   3% /mnt/batch/tasks
How do I tell nextflow to create my container with 200GB ?

From the documentation, it appears that the azure-batch executor does not support the disk directive. Have you tried using a queue with some larger nodes? Would a queue of the Standard_D8_v3 size be sufficient?
